# I am looking to filter data based on multiple conditions across different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, powerpivot, excel-365

Let's say I have this fictional table. This table shows me a fictional list of customers and the various claim type for the services they have decided to have, which outlet they went to, if they are a mammal or bird.

| Outlet | Name | Claim Type | Mammal/Bird | StatusToday | Date of Visit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North | Cat | Nails Trim | M | Paid | 1/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Nails Polish | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Second session | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Appeal | 11/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Rejected | 11/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 |
| South | Cat | Dance class | M | Appeal | 15/1/2023 |
| North | Cat | Dance class | M | Approved | 30/1/2023 |
| East | Dog | Nails Trim | M | Approved | 1/1/2023 |
| East | Dog | Second session | M | Approved | 2/1/2023 |
| South | Rabbit | Second session | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 |
| South | Parrot | Feather brush | B | Approved | 5/1/2023 |
| West | Parrot | Egg Care | B | Approved | 1/2/2023 |
| West | Cat | Egg Care | M | Rejected | 6/2/2023 |
| North | Dog | Nails Trim | M | Rejected | 2/2/2023 |

First, my task was to look for customers who has either paid or/and approved,  with investigate or/and rejected. This was achieveable with the add custom column via Power Query, which look something like

```
let
    customer = [Name],
    statusList = Table.SelectRows(#"Previous Step", each [Name] = customer)[StatusToday],
    paid = List.Contains(statusList, "Paid"),
    rejected = List.Contains(statusList, "Rejected"),
    approved = List.Contains(statusList, "Approved"),
    appealed = List.Contains(statusList, "Appealed"),
    allPaid = List.AllTrue(List.Transform(statusList, each _ = "Paid")),
    allRejected = List.AllTrue(List.Transform(statusList, each _ = "Rejected")),
    allApproved = List.AllTrue(List.Transform(statusList, each _ = "Approved")),
    allAppealed = List.AllTrue(List.Transform(statusList, each _ = "Appealed"))
in
    if ((rejected or appealed) and (paid or approved)) then "Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved"
    else if allPaid and not (approved or rejected or appealed) then "Paid All"
    else if allRejected and not (paid or approved or appealed) then "Rejected All"
    else if allApproved and not (paid or rejected or appealed) then "Approved All"
    else if allAppealed and not (paid or rejected or approved) then "Appealed All"
    else "Unknown Status"
```

So, it will look something like

| Outlet | Name | Claim Type | Mammal/Bird | StatusToday | Date of Visit | Custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| North | Cat | Nails Trim | M | Paid | 1/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Nails Polish | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Second session | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Appeal | 11/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Rejected | 11/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Fur brush | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| South | Cat | Dance class | M | Appeal | 15/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Cat | Dance class | M | Approved | 30/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| East | Dog | Nails Trim | M | Approved | 1/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| East | Dog | Second session | M | Approved | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| South | Rabbit | Second session | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Rejected All |
| South | Parrot | Feather brush | B | Approved | 5/1/2023 0:00 | Approved All |
| West | Parrot | Egg Care | B | Approved | 1/2/2023 0:00 | Approved All |
| West | Cat | Egg Care | M | Rejected | 6/2/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |
| North | Dog | Nails Trim | M | Rejected | 2/2/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved |

This custom column works, however, I have a huge list of data to work with (24,000~) and I would like to make it faster. In addition, I was asked to futher filter the data, where I look for the same or similar claim type, because sometimes, the salesperson submited the wrong claim.

For example, Cat, being a mammal, can only have services for "Nails Trim" not "Nail Polish". It is assumed that the data was entered wrongly because the first word is similar. So for the "rejected" claim,   it is closed, and traditionally the table would then look like this (i am not adovcating putting nail polish on birds, this is a fictional table.)

| Name | Claim Type | Mammal/Bird | StatusToday | Date of Visit | Custom | Case Status | Reasons |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Nails Trim | M | Paid | 1/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed |  |
| Cat | Nails Polish | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed | Ineligible |
| Cat | Second session | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed |  |
| Cat | Fur brush | M | Appeal | 11/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed | Mulitple claim |
| Cat | Fur brush | M | Rejected | 11/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed | Mulitple claim |
| Cat | Fur brush | M | Paid | 10/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed |  |
| Cat | Dance class | M | Appeal | 15/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed | Mulitple claim |
| Cat | Dance class | M | Approved | 30/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed |  |
| Dog | Nails Trim | M | Approved | 1/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved All | Closed |  |
| Dog | Second session | M | Approved | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed |  |
| Rabbit | Second session | M | Rejected | 2/1/2023 0:00 | Rejected All | Open |  |
| Parrot | Feather brush | B | Approved | 5/1/2023 0:00 | Approved All | Closed |  |
| Parrot | Egg Care | B | Approved | 1/2/2023 0:00 | Approved All | Closed |  |
| Cat | Egg Care | M | Rejected | 6/2/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Closed | Ineligible |
| Dog | Nails Trim | M | Rejected | 2/2/2023 0:00 | Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved | Open |  |

Cases that are "open" needs further investigation, and be manually input, which the reasons can be found out from other columns, etc, Cat, not being a bird, isn't eligble for "nail polish". (i am not adovcating putting nail polish on birds, this is a fictional table.)

In the idea world, I would be able to find those claims that are

1. Similar, paid/approved with rejected/appeal
2. Same, paid/approved with rejected/appeal
3. All rejected, all paid, all approved, all appeal...etc
4. For the "Second session", if they stand alone without any services rendered on the date before them and is rejected, to show as "Open" in the custom column

I have tried Pivot Table, but I wasn't able to produce the table I want. Additionally, someone asked me to find the outlets with the most "careless mistakes" (etc, nail polish instead of nail trim for cat), has many "second session" without the first session so we can go down to the store and educate the staff there. Is there another way I can load my custom column without the long waiting time? What excel knowledge do I need to learn so I can fulfilled my current work demands?

Comment: Can you explain in words why datarow 7 `['South', 'Cat', ....]` is not 'Rejected All' in the custom column in your 1st step? Same as to why `['West', 'Cat', ....]` is not 'Rejected All'. Are you only looking at the 'Name' and discarding the 'Outlet'? Meaning, the 'Name' is the same customer despite a different outlet?

Comment: Yep, name only, to claim type and status.

Comment: So if that's true, then why is your last sample `['North', 'Dog', ....]` equal to "Rejected All"?

Comment: You are right ,there is an error in my file...I'll fix it now...

Comment: You should edit the 2nd table to reflect this correction too. A 2nd question: Where do we find these "mistakes". I mean, do you have a lookup table where you'd go and specify each treatment possible by species? Without any info, how are we ought to understand what is a "mistake"?

Comment: They would have a similar text before them - etc nail polish vs nail trim....

Comment: So because they have the same leading word, but different trailing words, it is assumed that one of the options is actually a mistake? Are you saying that theoretically there is no species that could potentially have a nail polish and a nail trim? Are there any more such rules you need to be more clear about before someone tries to answer something that is very vague?

Comment: That is what my boss told me.... I cannot discuss the specific details here...By theoretically, no animal here can have both a nail polish and nail trim...

Comment: Bottom line here; without knowing what exactly is a mistake we can't help you. I gave a hint as to some sort of lookup table where you'd register eligable combinations of Species and Claim type. Without this, it's anyone's guess; I mean, how would an app like Excel be able to understand that `['Cat', 'Egg Care', ...]` as per your 13th sample is not a valid combination. Someone/something needs to tell Excel this is invalid.

Comment: I guess we can based it the animal species not being a bird?...

Comment: Then you are still not understanding the issue at hand. Excel **does not know** that a species that is not a bird can't have an 'Egg Care' treatment without any sort of determinating factor telling Excel that this is the case. Excel is not going to magically pull this information from an imaginary database. You would need to provide this logic!

Comment: How do I provide this logic? What do I need to learn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far as picking up errors, as pointed out by @JvDv you will need to develop a robust algorithm to determine which procedures are in error, or at least which to review.

For speeding up the generation of the Custom column, below ***might*** be faster.

See the code comments to better understand the algorithm.

I used the Table.Group method and a different method of determining the status comment.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Outlet", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Claim Type", type text}, {"Mammal/Bird", type text}, {"StatusToday", type text}, {"Date of Visit", type date}}),

//Add index column to retain original order
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//create Status List
    #"Status List" = List.Buffer({"Paid","Rejected","Approved","Appeal"}),

//Group by Name
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Index", {"Name"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [Outlet=nullable text, Name=nullable text, Claim Type=nullable text, #"Mammal/Bird"=nullable text, StatusToday=nullable text, Date of Visit=nullable date, Index=number]}}),

//Add custom column to output different statuses
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each 
        let
          Status = List.Intersect({#"Status List", [All][StatusToday]}, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase),
          Result = if List.Count(Status) = 0 then null
                    else if List.Count(Status) = 1 then Status{0} & " All" 
                    else if List.Count(Status) >= 3 then "Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved" 
                    else if List.Count(Status) = 2 
                            then 
                                if Status = {"Paid","Approved"} or Status = {"Rejected","Appeal"} then null else "Has rejection/appeal with paid/approved"
                    else null
      in 
        Result, type text),

//Re-expand grouped table
//Sort back to original order
//delete the Index column
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "All", {"Outlet", "Claim Type", "Mammal/Bird", "StatusToday", "Date of Visit", "Index"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded All",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Do i use a purely power query approach? Is there other tools within excel I could use?

Comment: That is entirely your decision. Deciding which tool to use of the many that are available is a bit off topic for this forum. You can explore and see which works best for you. Did this algorithm execute any more rapidly on your actual data set?

Comment: @ProperDataSet Made slight change in Custom Column formula that makes for easier readability and possibly better efficiency.

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your assistance, I'll run the formula once I am back at work (in around 16hours)

Comment: Hi Ron, is it necessary to list every single column in the custom formula? The columns in my original spreadsheet are more extensive than that, and I would need to type out every single column manually if I were to use your formula.

Comment: @ProperDataSet That's not really necessary. However, if you execute the table group function from the user interface, power query will generate that list automatically. If they are always the same, I would do it that way. If not, you can probably just delete the type clause from that line.

Comment: it is actually slower